# How to move inline css and js in main page?

Tags: wordpress

I'm using wordpress CMS System with a few plugin so these plugins are adding code my index.php so I want to move them another or my main js and cs files is that possible ? how can I move my inline js and css this is my first wordpress experiement and I look at functions.php I found nothing with pluging or without it how can I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin [**MinQueue**](https://wordpress.org/plugins/minqueue/) offers a solution. actually it doesn't do anything automatically but it allows you to configure what resources you want **concatenated** and in what order.

With the plugin active, in the Admin Bar on the front end you'll see a little helper link you can click.

another plugin for taking control of js and css : 
[Here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-script-optimizer/)

if you want to find codes manually i think this links will help ([Here](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/08/06/how-to-disable-scripts-and-styles))

Comment: hey thanks but last updated of MinQueue is 5 years ago and it doesn't work as i want it combined js and css but css and js file which is index.php has been not moved thank you

Comment: @ani_css i hoped it still work , how about this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-script-optimizer/

Comment: I've been already use this plugin but this is only minifed and combined my files I just want to move or combined my css and js files which is inline

Comment: if you know what are those inline css and java scripts then use this method https://davidwalsh.name/remove-stylesheets  ad finaly add them manually in style.css and javascript file. i hope it helps.

Comment: if it doesn't help please give me name of plugins which add inline css and i look at it too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174878/discussion-between-mohammad-and-ani-css).